# Getting rid of figure captions under figures

Tags: papaja

This is for Papaja.  How do I get rid of figure captions at the bottom of the figure.  My figure caption is quite long and I am going to a figure list.  Now, I get both, and the figure caption runs out on the bottom of the page.  Thanks, Jeff

Answer (score 1):

There are currently two options to accomodate long figure captions or tall figures. You can adjust the line spacing/font size or, as you are doing, use a separate list of figure captions. I'll briefly explain both approaches.

## 1. List of figure captions

### a) The LaTeX way

You can suppress the captions (defined by the chunk option `fig.cap`) below *all* figures by adding the following to the YAML front matter:

```
figurelist: yes

header-includes:
  - \captionsetup[figure]{textformat=empty}
```

### b) The `knitr` way

If you would rather suppress figure captions only where necessary you can instead get `knitr` to do this.

Set the figure short caption via the chunk option `fig.scap`. To ensure that `fig.scap` takes effect, `knitr` requires that the chunk specifies `out.width`, `out.height`, or `fig.align`, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27250635/short-caption-fig-scap-in-knitr-not-working). Remove the figure caption below the figure by setting `fig.cap = " "`.

Finally, I generally recommend to specify figure (and table) captions, especially long ones, using [text references](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/markdown-extensions-by-bookdown.html#text-references) (e.g., `(ref:reference-label)`. Taking all of this together, the following should do the trick:

````r
(ref:figure-caption) This is a long figure caption!

```{r fig.cap = " ", fig.scap = "(ref:figure-caption)", out.width = "\\textwidth", fig.height = 7}
plot(cars)
```
````

Make sure that you include `figurelist: yes` in the YAML front matter and that you are using at least the development version of `papaja` with the commit hash [`d6227d8a750c6e67a323828a7cb0b8b8331aeac7`](https://github.com/crsh/papaja/commit/d6227d8a750c6e67a323828a7cb0b8b8331aeac7), e.g. `devtools::install_github("crsh/papaja@d6227d8a750c6e67a323828a7cb0b8b8331aeac7")`.

## 2. Adjust line spacing and font size

As mentioned [in the manual](https://crsh.github.io/papaja_man/tips-and-tricks.html#adjusting-line-spacing), you can adjust the line spacing of figure captions. To additionally decrease the font size, add the following to the YAML front matter:

```
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{setspace}
  - \captionsetup[figure]{font={stretch=1,scriptsize}}
```

This should also make room for bigger captions or taller figures.